# Pasar consulta a Eloquent Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Hola tengo una duda en laravel 5.5 con una consulta en el orm,  como puedo hacer esta subconsulta, en mysql me funciona pero no puedo pasarla a laravel

```
select v.id as idvehiculo,
( select IFNULL(SUM(g.monto),0) as totalg 
  from gastos g 
  where g.id_vehiculo =v.id and  g.estado = 1) as totalg

 from vehiculos v
join ventas as v2 on v2.id_vehiculo = v.id
```

Muchas Gracias